# ExoPlayer problems trying to download current track

Tags: android, download, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using Exoplayer to create my own music player. I am also adding the option to download the track but I have a problem when I am trying to download the track that I am playing. I add a notification to the download to check the progress of the download and it appears but it even doesn't start. What I think is that it might have some kind of problem with the buffering cache and the download since they are stored in the same folder.

To download the tracks I do the following:

```
override fun addDownloadTrack(track: Track) {
    getIfTrackIsCached.run({ isCached ->
                               if (!isCached) {
                                   val data = Util.toByteArray(track.title.byteInputStream())
                                   val downloadRequest =
                                       DownloadRequest(track.id, DownloadRequest.TYPE_PROGRESSIVE, Uri.parse(track.href), Collections.emptyList(), track.id, data)
                                   DownloadService.sendAddDownload(context, ExoPlayerDownloadService::class.java, downloadRequest, false)
                               }
                           }, ::onError, GetIfTrackIsCached.Params(track.id))
}
```

This is the DownloadService:

```
class ExoPlayerDownloadService : DownloadService(
        FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID,
        DEFAULT_FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL,
        Constants.CHANNEL_DOWNLOAD_ID,
        R.string.exo_download_notification_channel_name) {

    private val manager: DownloadManager by inject()
    private val channelIsCached: ChannelPublisher<CachedMedia> by inject(PUBLISHER_IS_CACHED)
    private val notificationHelper: DownloadNotificationHelper by inject()

    private var nextNotificationId: Int = FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (!manager.isInitialized) {
            manager.maxParallelDownloads = MAX_PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS
        }
    }

    override fun getDownloadManager(): DownloadManager = manager

    override fun getForegroundNotification(downloads: MutableList<Download>?): Notification {
        var text = ""
        var index = 1
        downloads?.forEach { text += "${if (downloads.size > 1) "${index++} - " else ""}${Util.fromUtf8Bytes(it.request.data)}\n" }
        return notificationHelper.buildProgressNotification(R.drawable.ic_stat_downloading, null, text, downloads)
    }

    override fun getScheduler(): Scheduler? = null

    override fun onDownloadChanged(download: Download?) {
        val notification = when (download?.state) {
            Download.STATE_COMPLETED -> {
                channelIsCached.publish(CachedMedia(download.request.id, true))
                notificationHelper.buildDownloadCompletedNotification(R.drawable.ic_stat_download_complete, null, Util.fromUtf8Bytes(download.request.data))
            }
            Download.STATE_FAILED ->
                notificationHelper.buildDownloadFailedNotification(R.drawable.ic_stat_download_failed, null, Util.fromUtf8Bytes(download.request.data))
            else -> null
        }
        notification?.let { NotificationUtil.setNotification(this@ExoPlayerDownloadService, ++nextNotificationId, it) }
    }

    companion object {

        private const val MAX_PARALLEL_DOWNLOADS = 3
        private const val FOREGROUND_NOTIFICATION_ID = 2000
    }
}
```

And to create the cache I use this:

```
SimpleCache(File(androidContext().cacheDir, CACHE_MEDIA_FOLDER), NoOpCacheEvictor(), get<DatabaseProvider>())
```

How can I avoid conflicts between buffering cache and downloaded files?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue also, and found the solution!
[The downloading documentation states](https://exoplayer.dev/downloading-media.html#playing-downloaded-content)

> The CacheDataSource.Factory should be configured as read-only to avoid downloading that content as well during playback.

To do this you must call `setCacheWriteDataSinkFactory(null)` on your CacheDataSource.Factory object.

This will prevent the stream from writing to the cache, allowing the downloader to write as expected.